# read each cell values and store result in another column VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007

i have set of values in column A
need to select each cell value up to end of values entered

and after some operation i need to add the result in column B

A1 result to be stored in B1
A2  in B2

please help

Comment: Can you please comment your problem more?

Comment: Read the [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) to make your first steps into VBA. Then come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub LearnVBA()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        ' do something with each row
        ' for example add todays date to each cell
        Range("B" & c.Row) = Range("A" & c.Row) & Chr(32) & Now
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much... the above code is enough... :)